# Faster Multigrid Poission Equation Solver?

Tags: python, numpy, math, differential-equations

I am trying to make my own CFD solver and one of the most computationally expensive parts is solving for the pressure term. One way to solve Poisson differential equations faster is by using a [multigrid method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multigrid_method). The basic recursive algorithm for this is:

```
function phi = V_Cycle(phi,f,h)
    % Recursive V-Cycle Multigrid for solving the Poisson equation (\nabla^2 phi = f) on a uniform grid of spacing h

    % Pre-Smoothing
    phi = smoothing(phi,f,h);
    
    % Compute Residual Errors
    r = residual(phi,f,h);
    
    % Restriction
    rhs = restriction(r);

    eps = zeros(size(rhs));

    % stop recursion at smallest grid size, otherwise continue recursion
    if smallest_grid_size_is_achieved
            eps = smoothing(eps,rhs,2*h);
    else        
            eps = V_Cycle(eps,rhs,2*h);        
    end
    
    % Prolongation and Correction
    phi = phi + prolongation(eps);
    
    % Post-Smoothing
    phi = smoothing(phi,f,h);    
end
```

[I've attempted to implement this algorithm myself](https://github.com/mcleantom/CFDPython/blob/master/Fluid%20Dynamics/Multigrid%20Methods/Chapter%201/2D%20Poisson%20Solver.py) however it is very slow and doesn't give good results so evidently it is doing something wrong. I've been trying to find why for too long and I think it's just worthwhile seeing if anyone can help me.

If I use a grid size of 2^5 by 2^5 points, then it can solve it and give reasonable results. However, as soon as I go above this it takes exponentially longer to solve and basically get stuck at some level of inaccuracy, no matter how many V-Loops are performed. at 2^7 by 2^7 points, the code takes way too long to be useful.

I think my main issue is that my implementation of a jacobian iteration is using linear algebra to calculate the update at each step. This should, in general, be fast however, the update matrix A is an n*m sized matrix, and calculating the dot product of a 2^7 * 2^7 sized matrix is expensive. As most of the cells are just zeros, should I calculate the result using a different method?

if anyone has any experience in multigrid methods, I would appreciate any advice!

Thanks

Comment: You must include code you want checked here, not just behind a link.

Comment: Very interesting question. On the face of it, it sounds to me like something is wrong. 2^7 = 128 and 128 by 128 is not a large matrix these days. Expensive operations such as matrix inverse are O(n^3) so going from 2^5 by 2^5 to 2^7 by 2^7 should be a factor something like 4^3 which is only 64 ... I would expect operations for 2^5 to be lightning fast and then 2^7 would be slightly less than lightning fast. I guess at this point the question is, what are the expensive operations in your implementation?

Comment: I ran my code through a profiler and it said that the most expensive function was the "jacobian_update" function, of which the most expensive line was line 148 which is "vt = np.dot(Rj, vt) + np.dot(invD, f_inner)" which is the matrix form of a jacobian itteration. I would of thought this wouldnt be too slow but it takes 99.5% of the run time of the jacobian update function. I'm not sure how numpy works but Rj and invD are sparse matrices, so there is probably a lot of redundant calcuation if it is calculating 0 * some number